# What's the difference between "Voice input" and "On-device speech recognition"?

Tags: voice-recognition, input-methods

I've noticed that on my Android 13 device (a Pixel 5), in the `Languages & input` settings, there are two speech input related options:

- `Voice input`
- `On-device speech recognition`

both have the option to download languages, in order to be performed offline.

What's the difference between the two? The only context where I use voice/speech recognition is Google Keep Notes.

Comment: Just in case it matters, could you [edit] and mention the device model and whether you're using a custom ROM?

Comment: @AndrewT. done, thanks for the suggestion!